# Tabs appear above ActionBar when calling setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) in 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use `ActionBar` tab navigation mode and a `ViewPager`. This works fine in newer versions of Android, but on Android 4.0.3, tabs is in the top of the `ActionBar` instead of below.

If I use `ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)`, the problem appears to be fixed. However, up navigation then will not work.

[image: screen shot of Tabs appearing above ActionBar]

My code looks as follows

```
ActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.DocumentDetails);
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

ActionBar.Tab tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab.SetText("tab1");
tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
    // Do something when tab is selected
};
ActionBar.AddTab(tab);

tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab.SetText("tab2");
tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
    // Do something when tab is selected
};
ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this on an actual device? I have tested your code in an Emulator and can't reproduce. However, it does seem that several other people reported this to Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191

So a couple of ideas to fix this. Instead of using `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` try using the `DisplayOptions` property instead:

```cs
ActionBar.DisplayOptions = ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowHome | 
                           ActionBarDisplayOptions.HomeAsUp |
                           ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowTitle;
```

The important one is the `ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowHome` in this case, which forces the appearance of a home icon and `ActionBarDisplayOptions.HomeAsUp` does what `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` does. The last one I suppose you can guess.

If that does not help. There was one answer in that issue thread, which suggested to use an extension method to set the tab items as embedded into the `ActionBar`. However, that will look as if you are running on a tablet. The code is as follows:

```cs
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Lang.Reflect;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class ActionBarUtils
    {
        public static void SetHasEmbeddedTabs(Object inActionBar, bool hasEmbeddedTabs)
        {
            var actionBarClass = inActionBar.Class;

            if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJBMR2" == actionBarClass.Name)
            {
                actionBarClass = actionBarClass.Superclass.Superclass;
            }
            else if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB" == actionBarClass.Name)
            {
                actionBarClass = actionBarClass.Superclass;
            }

            try
            {
                var actionBarField = actionBarClass.GetDeclaredField("mActionBar");
                actionBarField.Accessible = true;
                inActionBar = actionBarField.Get(inActionBar);
                actionBarClass = inActionBar.Class;
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException) { }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException) { }
            catch (NoSuchFieldException) { }

            try
            {
                var method = actionBarClass.GetDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", new[] { Boolean.Type });
                method.Accessible = true;
                method.Invoke(inActionBar, new Boolean(hasEmbeddedTabs));
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException) { }
            catch (InvocationTargetException) { }
            catch (IllegalAccessException) { }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Then can be used like so in your `Activity`:

```cs
ActionBarUtils.SetHasEmbeddedTabs(ActionBar, true);
```